# How does cutting a biconvex lens in half along its principle axis affect its focal length?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Specifically how does cutting the lens in half affect the image? My textbook says that it only decreases its intensity but I can't find the justification.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a short quote of precisely what your textbook says? What does it say about focal length? When you have a problem like this, imagine what each lens half would do individually. Would the halves reduce image intensity or still focus parallel light into one point? If so, what would you expect as focal length? Does your textbook mention a formula for the focal length of lens combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Philip Wood's answer. Assuming the object under observation is a diffuse reflector (something like a wooden pole, or a wall, or whatever), every point on the object reflects light in all directions in a hemisphere centered on that point, sitting on the surface. This is why you can see things from different angles.

[image]
([image source](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/Converging-Lenses-Ray-Diagrams))

Now, what a lens does is: it collects rays emanating from a single source point on an object, that are initially going in somewhat different directions (within the spatial angle covered by the lens), and *redirects* them so that all of them converge to a single point in the image (you can almost think of it as of a "pixel").

In the diagram above, only three such rays are depicted, but there's a whole bunch of them omitted. Different rays hit the entire surface of the lens, everywhere, and they all contribute to the intensity of the corresponding point on the image (our metaphorical "pixel").

[image]
([image source](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/Converging-Lenses-Ray-Diagrams))

But the same thing happens for every point on the object:

[image]
([image source](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/Converging-Lenses-Ray-Diagrams))

Note that rays starting at different places in the source object converge at different points of the image, thus building up the whole picture.

Now, if you remove the bottom half of the lens, those rays will continue on their merry way, and will not contribute to the image intensity. But all the other rays will still converge where they are supposed to, still building up the entire image.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a lens forming a real image $I$ of a point object $O$.

[image]

The sketch shows the cone of rays which form the point image.

Removing the bottom of the lens means that the "red" rays no longer arrive at the image whereas the grey ray do, thus the intensity of the image is reduced.

If this were not so the [iris diaphragm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_(optics)#Iris_diaphragms_versus_other_types) in a camera would not be able to control the intensity of light reaching the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that rays parallel to, and not too far from, the axis *all* converge to a single point on the axis on the other side of the lens – the principal focus – at whatever point on the lens they strike it. So either half of the lens (cut as you have shown) will converge the rays to the principal focus.

Comment: Each half will converge parallel rays to a focal point on its side. I think I know what you mean, but it might be better if you could supply a drawing? I would give an upvote to an answer with such an illustration.

Comment: @FlatterMann Tell me what application I should install on my Mac to make such an illustration. [I am an IT ignoramus, but used to be a dab hand with the now unavailable Freehand].

Comment: Lots of people like to do a hand drawing on paper and they take a picture of it. Being old school I find that perfectly adequate, especially for physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann Sorry to be slow replying. I have occasionally included scans of hand-drawings, but there must be software out there that even I can use to draw a neat diagram!